# I wanted to use the feature selection in sas to know which of the features would affect the target (Note: Target consists of different ranges )

Tags: machine-learning, sas, feature-selection

Data set
SID, AVGAttendance , AVGAbsence, AVGGrade , AVGTotalduration , AVGofPracticaltasks, AVGTotalclicks.

Target variable is the (AMS) which has categorical data such I(Intrinsic motivation), ID(Identified regulation), E(External regulations)

I am trying to use the feature selection in SAS to know which of the features would affect the I, id and E

I used this code: ]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUNrH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiGyF.png)

Comment: Please post code in the question body, not in a screenshot. Having code in the question makes it easier for potential answerers to copy and paste

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.